# Autocomplete for opencart not working in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, opencart

When I add a product and I want to pick a category, I need to enter a letter and autocomplete will display the available categories there.

But nothing happens in Firefox. I have tried with Chrome and it works there with no issue.

I'll post a screenshot, maybe someone has an idea what is going on.

I use the default theme and most of the default settings.

Opencart version: 2.1.0.2

[image]

Comment: switch on browser console from developer option and see what the error says. Also check server logs for associated logging

Comment: And also see javascript is enable?

Comment: It's weird, javascript is enabled on my computer. I've tried from my laptop, using firefox and the autocomplete feature works there.